# Xcode4.2 : an error occurred uploading to the itunes store

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4, xcode4.2

Hey in trying to submit my app to iTunes. It passes the validation, but when i submit it's showing an error:

```
an error occurred uploading to the iTunes store
```

[image]

I have tried all possible solutions that I found during searching about this problem for almost one day .

```
I tried these lines without any success 
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
sudo ln -s CurrentJDK /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5
sudo ln -s CurrentJDK /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0
```

I use xcode 4.2 and snow leopard Mac OS .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the newest Application Loader to submit apps. For Snow Leopard Mac OS, you can download Application Loader 2.5 from [here](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_2.5.dmg) to see what the problem really is. If nothing else is wrong, you may get this error:

> This bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK, xcode.

I am also working on submitting apps with Xcode 4.2, because my macbook is too old to upgrade to Lion and to install Xcode 4.6. It seems that Xcode 4.2 is too old to be supported and the best solution is to install Xcode 4.6.

Answer (score 0):

This error says that there is something wrong with the upload process. I don't believe you can fix it without getting in touch with Apple.

I've had this error once (already some months ago). It was caused by a server side issue by Apple at that day, but today the Apple servers are working without any issues *(tried with Xcode 4.6)*.

Comment: So how can I get in touch with Apple ?

Comment: In iTunes Connect main menu interface is a button with 'Contact Us'.